# Error "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" on Telerik ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: piranha-cms

I start with Piranha for a week now, after read the documents and questions here I still can't solve the problem, so I post it here. Please help me. (I'm using Visual studio 2013 Update 2, Piranha 2.2.4)

- I tested Piranha on the template project. Everything is fine, now I create a Telerik ASP.NET MVC Q3 2014 project and follow the "Getting started" tutorial to add Piranha to an exist project. I got this error message (I also applied this issue https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/issues/277)

  http://pastebin.com/1B0WNA2V

When I remove Piranha and Piranha.MVC reference and add references from source project I get this error

```
http://pastebin.com/17CSziUK
```

Please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Piranha CMS uses **MEF** to import extensions into the framework. There's been issues before that some other projects don't play to nice with MEF, maybe the Telerik stuff you're using has this issue.

There's a fix coming in 2.3 where you can tell the framework to only scan the Piranha assemblies for extensions which would probably fix your issues. I'll see if I can deploy a patch for this!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks for answering. Will you release 2.3 soon?

Comment: Hi! I just notice that I solved my problem with this `INSTALL-PACKAGE Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`